# I have an open neutral on all electrical circuits

Tags: electrical

I have an open neutral on all circuits in my house. Everything is working fine. how do I fix this situation?

Comment: I'm confused. How did you determine you had an open neutral?  Usually that creates a bunch of dangerous problems

Comment: Oh dear, a “Magic 8-ball” tester.  First thing you do with one of those, is peel the sticker off, the one that says “open neutral”, and throw it in the trash.   If the 3 lights are red yellow yellow, the tester itself is at least useful.  If it’s red yellow green it can go in the trash also.  Needless to say you don’t have an open neutral.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I was thinking that too!  Either that or the OP has one heck of grounding system that could carry the neutral current (not likely at all, just jesting).

Comment: So would it make sense to measure hot to neutral voltage at a number of receptacles in the house and look for deviations from 120 V? These would be significantly below and above 120 V by the same absolute amount. Or would the best thing be to just get a better tester?

Answer (score 2):

turns out tester is faulty. checked with a new tester. neutral is fine.thank you for all responses.